# Which is the best approach for key value pair representation in mobile material ui

Tags: gui-design, android, material-design, ux-designer, google-materials-design

I am having limitted data for a page as given below

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| First name | John |
| Last name | Doe |
| Phone | +9099999999 |
| City | Chicago |

I want to represent the above data in an Android view. I tried to avoid table view like above. I am trying to show it as a material style. But in material documentation, I cannot find how to handle this. Could anybody share some insights or links.

Comment: It's a simple table, whether it's material design or some other system doesn't really affect it. I think your question is "Alternatives for table representation on mobile?". But I don't see how 2 columns is a problem on a mobile screen.

Comment: You could also [edit] your question to explain why do you want to avoid tables: is it the amount of data? difficulty of visualisation? Some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not editable you could use the solution proposed in the  [mindsphere blog](https://design.mindsphere.io/patterns/key-value.html):

- Have the key and value side by side on larger screens and above each other on smaller ones

[image]

[image]

- use individual font sizes to differentiate key and value, with key either above or below the value (the example below only shows key under value)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use textfields to display the data (if it is editable). The label above the textfield would be your key (https://material.io/components/text-fields#anatomy)

[image: textfield]

Comment: not editable. just viewing